# SFMC Reports - Analytics Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, custom-reports

Is there a way to produce report that doesn't concatenate the **[DATE]** & **[TIME]** into 1 field in a csv/xlsx?

I'm going to be making a dashboard for our internal team and this is messing with the scalability of that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this.  Unless someone can prove me wrong, one would have to take this data and adjust it in a 3rd party application (i.e. Microsoft Excel).